# Migrating from Spring MVC XML to Spring Boot Java based configuration with similar configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-aop

I am starting a new project. Previously I have used `Spring MVC, XML` based configuration. I am new to `Spring Boot` and tried to follow resources on web to start the new project, but I couldn't get it. Added required libraries and some simple setup but without success. Even Spring Security login is not successful, which I am doing of `XML` based one successfully.
My project setup is in `Spring Boot 1.5.9 RELEASE, which includes Spring Data, Spring AOP/AspectJ, Spring Security, Spring WebMvc, Hibernate, MySQL, HikariCP, Transaction Management, Jackson` and other relevant tech. `I am not using ThymeLeaf.` `With the current configuration, I even can't access the static contents form resources/static/**.`

I did tested `'aspect'` for `'@Controller'` calls and works well. And now I tried Spring Security basic login with `'JSP'` but couldn't get pass. I have uploaded the project setup in `GitHub`https://github.com/shakyasudeep/Spring-Boot-Setup-Config.

And I reviewed the `@Transactional` annotation for transaction management but it needs to be declared on every `@Service` which will be calling `DAO @Repository`, previously I implemented this one time in `XML` to reflect on the overall desired package.

The code is :

```
<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <!-- MUST have transaction manager, using aop and aspects  -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>    
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.eeposit.hub.dao"/>       

    <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" />
            <tx:method name="find*" read-only="true" />
            <tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRED" rollback-for="Throwable"/>
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>

    <aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="userServicePointCut"
                      expression="execution(* com.eeposit.hub.service.impl.*ServiceImpl.*(..))" />
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="userServicePointCut" />
    </aop:config>
```

I used `EntityManagerFactory` previously but now will be using `Spring Data`. I couldn't find a good reference for this(i.e.`Declarative Transaction` using Java code). How can we implement with just `Java Code` ?

Also I will also need `@Async as well as Scheduler` yet to configure.
And need to use message converters using Jackson, previously implemented by following code :

```
 <mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:message-converters>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="objectMapper">
                    <bean class="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper">
                        <property name="serializationInclusion" value="NON_NULL"/>

                    </bean>

                </property>
                <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json"/>
            </bean>

        </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>
```

File upload using :

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000" />
    </bean>
```

And external resource mapping :

Please provide some help/advice by committing to the GitHub repo. I will be here to review your valuable advice.

Comment: File upload, configured out-of-the-box, message converters configured out-of-the-box. Spring security configured out-of-the-box. Regarding transaction either use `@Transactional` on your services or simply add what you had in XML to java config. You can still have point cuts etc. defined as beans and have them applied.

Comment: Your main problem is that you are basically trying to work around Spring Boot. Don't, work with the framework instead of working around it.

Comment: Can you please commit a working Spring Security config.

Comment: Just remove your existing one, if you want to to extend the existing one remove `@EnableWebSecurity` (Spring Boot already does that for you) and add the additional configuration you need (like `formLogin`).

Comment: In your web configuration remove `@EnableWebMvc` en your custom config (Spring Boot already does that for you) and remove the view resolver as well (reinstate the `spring.mvc.view` properties in your `application.properties`). also you want to use JSP be aware of the limitations that has (I strongly suggest something like thymeleaf).

Comment: M.Deinum, If @EnableWebSecutity is removed, will authentication work.? Can you provide SpringBoot default configured features /functionalities? Or if possible please commit your suggestions to the Github repository https://github.com/shakyasudeep/Spring-Boot-Setup-Config, or please suggest me a pre-configured Spring Boot skeleton project which I can easily understand. I may not be using Thymeleaf, since jQuery or any one JS framework will take over frontend. And how to extend the existing one.? I will later be implementing database based user authentication.

Comment: I found @Import for XML import but couldn't find a good resource implemented, and it's working principle.

Comment: Hi, @M.Deinum, are you there ?

Comment: I suggest a read of the Spring Boot manual as that will explain what is enabled by default (depending on the dependencies you include). If you want to import xml use `@ImportResource` the `@Import` is for importing other `@Configuration` classes.

Comment: @M.Deinum, Thank you, I got through.